Named enums in TypeSpec
We're using TypeSpec to define a web API. One of the requirements is to add a larger enum to that API. My first, naive approach was the following:
/**
 * Enumeration of all possible device types.
 */
enum DeviceType {
    /**
     * Unknown DeviceType
     * UNKNOWN_DEVICETYPE
     * */
    UnknownDeviceType: -1,

    /**
     * Some other device type
     * OTHER_DEVICETYPE
     */
    OtherDeviceType: 0,

    /**
     * Some fancy device type
     * FANCY_DEVICE
     */
    SomeFancyDeviceType: 1,
    ...
}

Now, this code translates into the following using tsp compile and java -jar openapi-generator-cli-7.8.0.jar generate:
DeviceType:
  type: number
  enum:
    - -1
    - 0
    - 1

This gets converted into the following c# class:
/// <summary>
/// Enumeration of all possible device types based on table `dbo.DeviceTypes`.
/// </summary>
/// <value>Enumeration of all possible device types based on table `dbo.DeviceTypes`.</value>
public enum DeviceType
{
        
    /// <summary>
    /// Enum _1Enum for -1
    /// </summary>
    [EnumMember(Value = "-1")]
     _1Enum = 1,

    /// <summary>
    /// Enum _0Enum for 0
    /// </summary>
    [EnumMember(Value = "0")]
    _0Enum = 2,

    /// <summary>
    /// Enum _1Enum2 for 1
    /// </summary>
    [EnumMember(Value = "1")]
    _1Enum2 = 3,
   ...
}

As you can see, no names, no comments, just some weird and useless randomly generated enum members with random numbers. Is there a way to use the generate a proper enum description with TypeSpec?

Named enums are supported since OpenAPI 3.1, but I'm not aware of any codegens that support them already. You may need to fork and customize your codegens; or post-process the generated OpenAPI file and update the enum schemas as needed.

@Helen Are you aware of any pre-existing fork that already supports that?

No, haven't encountered any as yet.

Thank you. Maybe someone else has an idea.
